# Function In Twilio that calls API Post Request

Tags: function, twilio

Is there an example of triggering Lambda function by Call instead of SMS. I have An 3rd API Post Request that I am using the only problem is while using Twilio studio HTTP REQUEST Widget there is no place to put authorization information for that API Post. Is there an example function that you have that has Authorization for API Request Post that uses IVR Voice.

Need a place to put authorization information on the HTTPS Request Widget( AccessKey and SecretKey) Or example Function that calls an API with authorization.

Answer (score 1):

If there are special headers you need, rather then basic authentication over HTTPS, you will need to use the Studio [Run Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#run-function) Widget. There is an example of writing a Twilio Function to make an 3rd party API call found here, [Building apps with Twilio Functions (Beta)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions-Beta-), "How do I call 3rd party REST APIs?".